# Solution verification of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigg\lvert\frac{(b^{n+1}(n+1)^2-4)(n^2+1))}{(b^{n}n^2-4)((n+1)^2+1))}\Bigg\rvert$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I have to compute the following limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigg\lvert\frac{(b^{n+1}(n+1)^2-4)(n^2+1))}{(b^{n}n^2-4)((n+1)^2+1))}\Bigg\rvert$$
Here my attempt:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigg\lvert\frac{(b^{n+1}(n+1)^2-4)(n^2+1))}{(b^{n}n^2-4)((n+1)^2+1))}\Bigg\rvert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigg\lvert\frac{b^{n+1}n^4}{b^{n}n^4}\Bigg\rvert=|b|$$
I have tried to check the solution in WolframAlpha but this gives me an error.

So **can you tell me if I am right?**

(**Remark:** in the last but one passage I have thought to select only the dominant terms that are $b^{n+1}n^4$ and $b^n n^4$, since $n^4$ goes to $\infty$ faster than all the other $n^k$ that appear in the limit)

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but "leaving only dominant terms" is an informal move. Backup it with a lemma/a proposition, or just prove it. As it is now, for me, it is insufficent to be considered a proof since clearly you are learning doing such computations, thus you shouldn't adhere to informal moves yet.

Comment: Also, your solution breaks for $b=0$.

Comment: mmm I don't know ho solve this limit with another via...can you help me?

Comment: The method is okay, but it requires better presentation. What you could do to improve it: - recall what a limit is(the Couchy definition) - observe(proof) that from the definition sums and quotients of converging things converge if the denominator doesn't converge to zero - then finally observe that $\frac{1}{n^k}$ converges to zero. This gives you a path to nicely do the following with full understanding: multiply numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{n^4}$ and observe what converges to zero, what is left and that there are no further problems, at least for $b\ne 0$. Then do the case $b=0$.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! I will try to do as suggested by you!